# Synonym suggestion: [senses] and [perception]

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

As title suggests. I was about to put [senses](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/senses) and then realised that [perception](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/perception) already exists.

If you think they are sufficiently different to warrant two tags, I think [senses](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/senses) should be created.

Off-topic: Am I doing this right?  I didn't find any pre-built way to suggest a synonym so I figured I'd ask here :)

Comment: This is a perfectly fine way to do it, there *is* a prebuilt way but it's [quite complicated](http://biology.stackexchange.com/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms) and I don't think you have sufficient tag score for "perception" to create them through that system anyway as yet. "Users with more than 1250 reputation and a total answer score of 5 or more on the tag, can suggest tag synonyms. Users with a total answer score (total upvotes minus total downvotes) of 5 or more on the tag, can vote for tag synonyms..."

Comment: Consider asking on CogSci.SE where there is both the [perception](http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/perception) and [sensation](http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sensation) tags and the questions are unambiguously on-topic.

Comment: Perception and sensation are two different topics imo.