# Synonimizing the tags 'senses' and 'sensory systems'

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

Is it an idea to make the tag **[sensory systems](https://biology.stackexchange.com/edit-tag-wiki/3372)** the leading tag and [synonimize](https://biology.stackexchange.com/tags/senses/synonyms) the [senses](https://biology.stackexchange.com/edit-tag-wiki/2211) tag with it? I can't vote to do this, as I created the [sensory systems](https://biology.stackexchange.com/edit-tag-wiki/3372) tag. The [senses](https://biology.stackexchange.com/edit-tag-wiki/2211) tag info is currently not created and a simple link to sensory systems solves it.

Even better imo, I can **change the existing senses tags into sensory systems**, thereby auto-deleting the senses tag.

Thing is, the senses are generally viewed at as vision, smell, taste, touch and hearing. Sensory systems also includes the vestibular system, propriocepsis, haptics at large, among others. It's more encompassing imo.

I have thrown it in here, as 'senses' is a more common and more colloquial term. Since I am not a native English speaker, other more English-language-proficient people may object and might prefer senses, or might prefer to keep them separate. Folks might find my proposal inappropriate for other reasons.

There has been an [earlier proposal](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/319/synonym-suggestion-senses-and-perception) to synonimize [perception](https://biology.stackexchange.com/edit-tag-wiki/222) and [senses](https://biology.stackexchange.com/edit-tag-wiki/2211). I vote against this, as perception enters the CogSci domain, while sensory systems is as Bio as it can be. Both tags should definitely stay, but separate imo.

Answer (score -1):

I would prefer [senses](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/senses) over [sensory-systems](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sensory-systems) since it is simpler and more well-known. The tag description can still explain that the vestibular system and other sensory systems are also included. Either way, irrespectively of direction, synonymizing them is a good idea. This issue is probably best solved by a discussion here followed by moderator action though, since so few users can vote for specific tags.

Comment: Downvote for preferring "sensory-systems" over "senses" or for another reason?

Comment: Downvote just for disagreeing; I like your answer though and that's exactly why I asked the question. Since your answer is the only one, I might indeed just let it rest for now. Meta is more like a voting system I guess, I dislike downvoting, but here I just vote with it. No offense.

Comment: @Christiaan That's ok. Either way, since so few can vote on suggested synonyms, a moderator probably will have to act on this to make it happen.